# Rust: static, const, new and traits

Tags: rust, traits

Let we have the simple trait:

```
trait Object {
    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;
}
```

and the struct implemented this trait:

```
struct Foo { /* internal fields */ }

impl Object for Foo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { /* some magic */ }
    }
}
```

Now we want to declare static variable in `main.rs`, for example:

```
static FOO: Foo = Foo::new();
```

but we immediately get

> error[[E0015](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0015)]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants

So, if we want to construct static variables of `Foo` type, we should declare a function like `new`, but it should be different function, for example:

```
impl Foo {
    const fn const_new() -> Self { Self { } }
}

static FOO: Foo = Foo::const_new();
```

But `const`-twins of trait functions seems very odd. Is there an idiomatic way to write/implement such `const` counterparts?

**UPDATE**

I expand answer of @KevinReid for clarity here. Given code works:

```
pub trait Object {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

pub struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    pub const fn new() -> Self { // (1)
        Self {}
    }
}

impl Object for Foo {
    fn new() -> Self { // (2)
        println!("A-HA!");
        Self::new() // no recursion, calls (1)
    }
}

const FOO: Foo = Foo::new(); // calls (1)

fn main() {
    let obj: Foo = Object::new(); // calls (2)
    let foo = Foo::new(); // calls (1)
}
```

This [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2565ad3fda9938e4038bbf5a51b9d50c) on Rust Playground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename `const_new` to just `new`. When a trait method and an inherent method have the same name, the inherent method is always picked; it is not considered ambiguous.

This way, the same call can be written in both const and generic contexts, and there is no unusual name. (I would also suggest documenting the two functions to mention each other, so people don't assume that because one exists the other doesn't.)

That said, I can't say this idea is *idiomatic;* I haven't seen it done in a library I've used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Rust compiler's recommendation, this is the idiomatic solution:

```
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

static FOO: Lazy<Foo> = Lazy::new(Foo::new);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=9ff656001cb82f5da2bdceccb1bb0e69)